# Github CI “No such file or directory” while local run is fine

Tags: python, docker, github-actions

I have a workflow document that runs unit tests. On Github CI it was giving me File Not Found error when running the last line. But everything was fine when I run it on my local windows machine. I even changed the github OS to windows-latest to double-check. What am I doing wrong here?

```
runs-on: windows-latest

steps:
- uses: actions/checkout@v2
- name: Set up Python 3.8
  uses: actions/setup-python@v2
  with:
    python-version: 3.9
- name: Install dependencies
  run: |
    python -m pip install --upgrade pip
    pip install flake8 pytest
    # if \[ -f requirements.txt \]; then pip install -r requirements.txt; fi
    pip install -r requirements.txt
- name: Lint with flake8
  run: |
    # stop the build if there are Python syntax errors or undefined names
    flake8 . --count --select=E9,F63,F7,F82 --show-source --statistics
    # exit-zero treats all errors as warnings. The GitHub editor is 127 chars wide
    # flake8 . --count --exit-zero --max-complexity=10 --max-line-length=127 --statistics
- name: Test with pytest
  run: |
    # pytest
    python -m unittest discover linux64/unittest
```

Here's the error message:

```
    ERROR: test_hk_resource_count (unittest.loader._FailedTest)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
ImportError: Failed to import test module: test_hk_resource_count
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\hostedtoolcache\windows\Python\3.9.6\x64\lib\unittest\loader.py", line 436, in _find_test_path
    module = self._get_module_from_name(name)
  File "C:\hostedtoolcache\windows\Python\3.9.6\x64\lib\unittest\loader.py", line 377, in _get_module_from_name
    __import__(name)
  File "D:\a\hammerkop-backend\hammerkop-backend\linux64\unittest\test_hk_resource_count.py", line 17, in <module>
    settings.init()
  File "D:\a\hammerkop-backend\hammerkop-backend\linux64\unittest\..\settings.py", line 522, in init
    init.unique = loadlibrary_yamlfile(file2open, reference="reference")
  File "D:\a\hammerkop-backend\hammerkop-backend\linux64\unittest\..\settings.py", line 481, in loadlibrary_yamlfile
    with open(filepath) as fp:
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'reference\\buildingblocks2_10.yaml'

[enter image description here][1]
```